# rails get a list from two separate models that have similar features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I need to make a consolidated list of payable services, with filtering, ordering and pagination (with willpaginate gem) the payable services are stored in two separate models, `Application` and `Support`, both have similar fields (that I need to show in the columns) but I would need to have both in the same query.

here's my situation:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  // name, created_at, price ... 
  has_many :supports
end

class Support < ActiveRecord::Base
  // name, application_id, created_at, price ... 
  belongs_to :application
end
```

and the controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  FILTER_STRINGS = {
    requested: { reference_status: 'requested' },
    sent: { reference_status: 'sent' },
    completed: { reference_status: 'completed' }
  }

  ORDER_STRINGS = {
    name: 'name %1$s',
    price: 'price %1$s',
    date: 'created_at %1$s'
  }

  def payable_list
    @applications = Application.all
    @applications = @applications.where(FILTER_STRINGS[filter_params[:filter].to_sym]) if filter_params[:filter]
    order_string = format(ORDER_STRINGS[sort_params[:sort].downcase.to_sym], sort_params[:dir])
    @applications = @applications.order(order_string)
    @applications = @applications.paginate(page: params[:page] || 1, per_page: 20)
  end
...
end
```

The controller currently only loads the Application, but I need to include the Support items as well, in the view I will append the string '(Support)' for support items, to differentiate the items.

How could I include both models in the same `ActiveRecord_Relation`, so that I can sort them together? I would have no issues with using Ruby to sort the lists, but then I'd have problems with will paginate who seems to only work with `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

I tried using a join clause, but that still returns an Application object

```
Application.joins('JOIN supports ON "supports"."application_id" = "applications"."id"')
```

I tried `union` as well, with this command:

```
Application.find_by_sql("SELECT 
'application' AS role,
applications.id AS id, 
applications.price AS price, 
applications.application_id AS application_or_support, 
to_char(applications.created_at, 'DD Month YYYY, HH24:MI') AS created_at, 
FROM applications
UNION
select 
'support' AS role,
supports.id AS id, 
supports.price AS price, 
supports.support_id AS application_or_support, 
to_char(supports.created_at, 'DD Month YYYY, HH24:MI') AS created_at, 
from supports;")
```

but it's only giving me the columns that have a match in the `applications` model.

I'm thinking that maybe I could make a new model not backed by a DB table, where the rows would originate from that union query, but I wouldn't know how to go about the syntax to get it done.

Comment: If you want to combine the results from two different tables you need to use the SQL [UNION keyword](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-union-overview-usage-and-examples/)   - something which is not built into ActiveRecord and which may be very difficult to accomplish.

Comment: thanks that's what I was working on, updated the question

Comment: maybe creating an ad hoc model (not backed by an actual DB table, but rather by that query) would work, but I'm not sure how to go about the syntax

Comment: An SQL view might be able to work here and to ActiveRecord it will act as a single table. You might be able to use the "type" column to use Rails STI type inference mechanism.

Comment: I'm implementing it as a model based on the view, and it's working, great idea to use the STI, I'm doing it and it works great.